# Replace everything is displayed at Linux ubuntu startup by an image

Tags: linux, image, ubuntu, startup, splash-screen

I'm currently developing a GUI on a Pandaboard with ubuntu.
I'd like to only show a given image on the screen at startup in order that the user only show the image and then the program I developed.

In order to do that, I configured autologin, autolaunch the program at startup but I don't know how to display an image on screen until the program is ready to be launched.

Is this possible ? Does anyone know how to do that ?

Regards